# Use type name instead of the !type value in code completion

Tags: javascript, ternjs

I have a function which has a resultData parameter with the type of DataView.
This looks like the following in the code completion tooltip.

```
...resultData: fn(buffer: +ArrayBuffer, byteOffset?: number, byteLength?: number)...
```

My preffered code completion would be:

```
...resultData: DataView...
```

Is that somehow managable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reaching out one of the Tern.js developers he answered the following:

"Not really. Tern doesn't use type names when showing function types, because those would usually be unhelpful."